# Two-page view in full screen for Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, fullscreen, adobe-acrobat

Since i'm using a wide screen, i want to view two page in full screen while reading PDF. I can view two page in Reading Mode or normal view. however, whenever i switch to full screen mode, acrobat show only one page. I guess there must be some way to view two page when you're in full screen mode in Adobe Acrobat?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In adobe reader 9.3.3

First, select two page view as normal:
view->page display->two up

Then, change your fullscreen preferences:
edit->preferences->full screen->fill screen with one page at a time (uncheck)

Comment: Similar solution also works on Foxit Reader.

Comment: you are my hero

Comment: Iuupiii! I don't understand why this isn't the default. So much better and faster to read documents! (I guess people print because they don't know how to read in this way :) eheheh)

Comment: ..and here we go again :)