# Adobe readers won't display 2 pages in full screen

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, fullscreen, display-settings

There's an almost 6 year old question about this ([Two-page view in full screen for Adobe Acrobat](https://superuser.com/questions/250100/two-page-view-in-full-screen-for-adobe-acrobat/1160418?noredirect=1#comment1671938_1160418)) that I came across while searching for a solution.

In Acrobat Reader DC (version 2015.020.20042) on a Windows 10 machine.
I click on 
View | Page Display | Two Page View 
and the page look great. But the moment I click on full screen I have a single page filling up the middle of my screen with massive amounts of emptiness on both sides. 

Thinking that the problem was the new reader, I uninstalled Acrobat Reader DC and installed (downgraded to?) Adobe Reader XI and still had the same problem. Two pages viewed nicely in "windowed" mode, but the moment I went to full screen I had only a single page showing at a time.

To summarize, I'm on Win 10, I've tried both ARDC and ARXI and both refuse to show 2 pages in full screen mode.


Does anyone have a solution to this?  I swear that sometime in the past, I was able to view 2 pages in full screen mode.

Comment: Did you actually follow all of the steps in the answer you linked? It seems like you did one step, but not the other. I just modified by settings and it worked perfectly fine. I think you missed this one **Then, change your fullscreen preferences: edit->preferences->full screen->fill screen with one page at a time (uncheck)**

Comment: DrZoo - Your comment was the answer, thank you.
I couldn't figure out how to upvote your comment, so I added it as an answer.  
If you can post your comment as an answer I'll delete mine.
Thanks again.

Comment: No need to me to make an answer since it's a duplicate. I just reemphasized some of the steps involved. I'll vote to close it as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you encounter is absolutely normal.

Full screen means that a single page is displayed, fitting on the full screen, with a "neutral" background.

Possible workarounds:

• In the document properties deactivate all the window controls in the display options. This will allow for displaying two pages, but you won't have the neutral background.

• "Refry" the document (send through a printer (driver) to create a new PDF, while setting the 2 pages on a sheet option in the printer settings. The result is another single page which can be displayed full screen, but it contains two former pages. **However**, with this procedure, you will lose a lot of sometimes very important information of the document, such as annotations, links, fields, structure etc.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to DrZoo, I did miss this step:
I now have a 2 page full screen view on Acrobat Reader XI - Thank you.

Did you actually follow all of the steps in the answer you linked? It seems like you did one step, but not the other. I just modified by settings and it worked perfectly fine. I think you missed this one Then, change your fullscreen preferences: edit->preferences->full screen->fill screen with one page at a time (uncheck) – DrZoo Dec 30 '16 at 19:50